# Having trouble with Android manifest configuration

Tags: java, android

I following along with *Beginning Android Games* book, and at the end of Chapter 6 (for those familiar with the book) I screwed up the manifest file somehow and I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the main activity class.

The game consists of three packages:

- com.badlogic.androidgames.framework
- com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl
- com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.mrnom

  ```
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="5"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".MrNomGame"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>
  </manifest>
  ```

the class `MrNomGame` is located in the com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom package. If it's not obvious, I'm extremely new to android dev and I can't wrap my head around how java and android (manifest) discern file locations, among about 8 billion other questions.

Thanks.

EDIT: Main activity and Logcat output:

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom;

import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.Screen;
import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGame;

public class MrNomGame extends AndroidGame {

    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this);
    }
}
```

as per Robby Pond's suggestion, I updated the manifest `android:name:` to `android:name=".mrnom.MrNomGame"` and this is the logcat output after that change.

```
02-27 10:01:21.039: D/AndroidRuntime(1261): Shutting down VM
02-27 10:01:21.039: W/dalvikvm(1261): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3affba8)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Process: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom, PID: 1261
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom/com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNomGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:136)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:30)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGame.onCreate(AndroidGame.java:44)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     ... 11 more
02-27 10:06:21.749: I/Process(1261): Sending signal. PID: 1261 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please provide the full Manifest and especially the activity where the exception occurs along with the logcat output

Comment: you cut the important part from the manifest..

Comment: Sorry guys, I copy->pasted->CTRL+K and it got cut off. It's fixed now

Comment: there is a null pointer exception at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:30)
02-27 10:01:21.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGame.onCreate(AndroidGame.java:44)

Answer (score 1):

If your package name in the manifest is `com.badlogic.androidgames` then you need to change `.MrNomGame` to `.mrnom.MrNomGame`. Names in the manifest are relative to the classname in the manifest. Also you can change the activity android:name to the fully classified package/class name.

Comment: I updated the manifest and still get NullPointerException see update above.

Comment: Now your problem is inside Activity - at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:30) - look to row 30

Answer (score 0):

Add the absolute pass of the `Activity` not the name only. Example:

```
android:name="com.example.package.MrNomGame"
```

Comment: There is a shortcut: Writing '.<NAME>' is short for '<PACKAGENAME>.<NAME>' where <PACKAGENAME> is defined in the <manifest> tag of the manifest file.